# Open CV import is not working

Tags: python, opencv

everyone,

I have been working my senior design which involves the capturing of face coordinates and sending them to later be processed, now with my research I have found the OpenCV with python is the best way to do this, but I have failed multiple times to import OpenCV into python, always giving me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have tried almost every solution, and now im at a point where I wish to know if there is any other way to use a webcam to capture the coordinates of a human face without the usage of openCV, and this should be done in real time. im trying to use such projects:

https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam/

Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please give a glimpse of the OS you are using, the version of python and the version of OpenCV you have installed on your system? You can try installing anaconda it includes most of the packages of python and it's pretty easy to install and use OpenCV cv2 with it.

Comment: I am running windows 10 64-bit, and installing the latest version of OpenCV along with the latest python IDE I found I will try to check anaconda and will keep you updated, thank you for your help

Comment: use the following link  http://mathalope.co.uk/2015/05/07/opencv-python-how-to-install-opencv-python-package-to-anaconda-windows/

Comment: Thank you Arjun, I did the steps included in the link you provided and everything is working fine now

Comment: well, you can tick this as the correct answer then and give me an upvote

Comment: I wish I can, I need 15 reputation or above in order to upvote something

Comment: You don't have to upvote it. You just have to mark it as correct answer